# Command line to update SVN folders

Tags: svn, command-line, powershell

I have tried several things so far, but I haven't had much luck yet. I'm attempting to have a command line or PowerShell script that I can run once a day to make sure my numerous checked-out projects are up to date.

I know I would be looping through the directory folders inside my workspace, but when setting the variables I haven't had any luck as it will error out. I am using [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN), and [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista).

Here is what I have so far:

```
echo == Initiating system instance variables...
echo. -- Setting the variables...

:: Here you need to make some changes to suit your system.
set SOURCE=C:\workspace\Project
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
:: Unless you want to modify the script, this is enough.

echo. %SOURCE%
echo. %SVN%
echo. ++ Done setting variables.
echo.
echo == Updating source from SVN
echo. -- Running update...
"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"%SOURCE%" /closeonend:2
echo. ++ Done.

echo. -- Cleaning up...
set SOURCE=
set SVN=
echo. ++ Done.

@echo off
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Also, making this a simple .bat file should do the trick.

Comment: Ummm... Why do you have to use TortoiseSVN?  It makes far more sense to use the regular win32 svn commandline client, primarily because the regular client was designed from the get-go for command line work and automation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It might be easier in PowerShell:

```
Set-Alias tsvn 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe'
dir C:\workspace | %{ tsvn /command:update /path:"$($_.FullName)" /closeonend:2 }
```

Or if you want to specify certain project directories:

```
cd C:\workspace
$projects = 'Proj 1','Proj 2','Proj 3'
$projects | %{ tsvn /command:update /path:"$_" /closeonend:2 }
```

PowerShell scripts have a ps1 extension. You might also have to update the execution policy to allow scripts to run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: how would it a list of folders to loop over and what is the extension of PowerShell scripts, I really like it, its a lot simpler than the older script I had going on

Answer (score 10):

Just use the SVN command line itself:

```
pushd "%SOURCE%"
svn update
popd
```

You can get the Subversion tools for Windows at http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#windows. Install them side by side with TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Unless installed separately, tortoise doesn't come with the command line interface.

Comment: Actually, there is a command line tool that comes with Tortoise (SubWcRev.exe).

Comment: No, sorry, we use it to update out source files with a rev. number, it cannot be used to update/commit.