# How to do SVN Update on my project using the command line

Tags: svn, command-line

How do I SVN Update my project using the command line?

Then I will manage to call these command lines from C#.

I'm a .NET developer, and I'm using [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN).

Comment: possible duplicate of [command line to update svn folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034186/command-line-to-update-svn-folders)

Comment: be prepared to resolve conflicts in command line :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I got it. It's:

```
"SVN Client Path"  /command:update / path:"My folder path"
```

Comment: that works with Tortoise, but if you're driving the command line, get and use the 'native' command line tool (called svn.exe) from collabnet's website.

Answer (score 67):

```
svn update /path/to/working/copy
```

If subversion is not in your PATH, then of course

```
/path/to/subversion/svn update /path/to/working/copy
```

or if you are in the current root directory of your svn repo (it contains a .svn subfolder), it's as simple as

```
svn update
```

Comment: I've just tested this and it works. Question is what happens if there are conflicts? Will it automatically launch the merge tool of choice, or a GUI with a list of conflicted files that you can merge or something like that?

Comment: @Jacques: Nope, you get command-line output, telling you that the update didn't take place. (So either it's time to go for the resolve commands, or  (as I do) fire up [smartSVN](http://www.smartsvn.com/))

Comment: Additional advice: The 1st version (independent of current directory) is what you want, if you write yourself a `update_my_entire_project.sh|bat`

Comment: I use tortoiseSVN and update the Project the code which is in POM.xml nevere updates is there something I am doing wrong or tortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 19):

From the command line it would be just:

```
svn update
```

(in the directory you've got a copy of a SVN project).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to update your project using SVN then first of all:

1. Go to the path on which your project is stored through command prompt.
2. Use the command `SVN update`

That's it.